# unix command execution with password via python

Tags: python, mysql, unix

I am trying to connect to mysql in unix from a python script. I provided the password to connect to mysql in the script itself but terminal still prompts for the password. This is what i have till now:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

passwd = "user"
command = "mysql -u root -p"

proc = Popen(command.split(), stdin=PIPE)
proc.communicate(passwd+'\n')[1]
```

Can any one suggest what am i doing wrong here. Or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Many apps don't use `stdin` for password prompt for security reasons.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225542/how-can-i-interact-with-another-program-in-python

Comment: From the mysql doc:  *Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. You can use an option file to avoid giving the password on the command line.*  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your script in Ubuntu 14.04. It is very easy to start a MySQL in terminal using shell script.
Here is the code..

```
#!/bin/bash       
user=('root')
pass=('XXX')
mysql -u $user -p$pass
echo 'success'
```

Simply run this code & you can start the MySQL at terminal...

Comment: What are the brackets all about around the user and pass values?

Comment: Really?  That doesn't create a constant for me, in bash I use `declare -r`.  Which version of `bash` is that in?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11

Comment: I misunderstand variable declaration. Brackets used for array declaration.

Comment: And that was introduced in Bash 4, prior to that the parentheses are ignored.  By the way, it is good practice to put double quotes around variable expansions (`"$pass"') in case there is embedded whitespace.

Comment: Thanks...i finally used shell script only..then i simply called this shell script from python..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
command = "mysql -u root -p" + passwd
```

Comment: @harshul gandhi hi, please mark this answer if you find it correct. Thanks

Comment: tried that, it prompts me to enter password on terminal

Comment: The command will look like:  "mysql -u root -puser" for your case.